# This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined] Failing descriptor:

Tags: lightning

---

```
<aura:component >
    <a onclick = "{!c.createRecord}">Test</a>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": "0017F00000VA26WQAT",
      "slideDevName": "detail"
    });
    navEvt.fire();
}
})
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, and works for me, perhaps the problem lies elsewhere

Answer (score 3):

This feature is only available in LEX, Communities, and S1. If you're writing a custom app (AuraDefinitionBundle with an ".app" file), or using Lightning Out (including Visualforce), this event is not registered and will result in an error. Try adding your component to a Record Detail Page or Home Page to have it work correctly.